# Is ID Verify expected to work with iOS 16.0 in simulator yet?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-wallet

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let controller = PKIdentityAuthorizationController()
    let descriptor = PKIdentityDriversLicenseDescriptor()
    lazy var button: PKIdentityButton = {
        let button = PKIdentityButton(label: .verifyIdentity, style: .black)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onClickButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    @objc
    func onClickButton(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        descriptor.addElements([.age(atLeast: 18)],
                               intentToStore: .willNotStore)
        descriptor.addElements([.givenName,
                                .familyName,
                                .portrait],
                               intentToStore: .mayStore(days: 30))
        
        controller.checkCanRequestDocument(descriptor) { [weak self] canCreateRequest in
            guard let self = self else {return}
            if canCreateRequest {
                self.view.addSubview(self.button)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    self.button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
                    self.button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
                ])
            } else {
                print("No Apple ID flow")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func createRequest() -> PKIdentityRequest {
        let request = PKIdentityRequest()
        request.descriptor = descriptor
        request.merchantIdentifier = ""
        return request
    }
}
```

This code is giving No apple ID flow with console error

[15990:228937] [Client] DigitalPresentmentClient canRequestDocument error: Not entitled

[15990:228938] [Client] DigitalPresentmentSession checkCanRequestDocumentType error from
xpc: Not entitled

is There anything we need to do to get for Requesting identity data from a Wallet pass.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/wallet/requesting_identity_data_from_a_wallet_pass

Comment: Did you managed to run it?

Answer (score 0):

As error suggest, you have not added wallet capability in identifier. So, Please add wallet capability in application identifier from developer account first.